# In Amazon AWS, how can I trigger a lambda function to execute only once per ELB health check cycle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a classic load balancer connected to three instances. Currently I am able to trigger a lambda function successfully upon health check. However the Lambda is triggered by each of the three instances.

I want the lambda function to only be called once per health check cycle. Is something like this possible? I thought that perhaps there was a CloudWatch event that could be sent, however I can't seem to find any documentation that something like this exists.

Can you think of any novel solutions to this problem?